# Descriptions of frequency versus present tense

Tags: word-usage, verbs, syntactic-analysis, present-tense

Is there ever a difference between descriptions of frequency and the present tense?

For example, is there a difference between "I speak English." (referring to  frequent speaking of English) and "I speak." (in present tense, as you might see in a first-person narrative)?

If so, what is it? If not, why isn't there a difference between the two?

I apologize for my vagueness in use of the word "difference". I'm asking for any sort of difference, even at the most general level, in how the two are used in a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'difference'.  They are both 'habitual' present.  'I am speaking' would convey the present (progressive).  Many other languages do not make this distinction.